# How to copy table from excel to word using VB

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate the production of a word document (.docm) using data from my excel (.xlsm) using a VB macro.

Currently i'm able to copy some parts of the information from the excel to the word document.
The problem is that i can't find a solution to pass the table information to the word bookmark.

```
Sub Word()

Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim WDDoc As Word.Document
Dim BMRange As Word.Range
Dim cliente As Range
Dim CPE As Range
Dim localidade As Range
Dim numproposta As Range
Dim DIRECT, saveAsName, data As String
Dim table1 As Table

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'Create an instance of word
Set WDDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\PT13217294\test.docm") 'Open word file
wdApp.Visible = True

'excel ranges
'Windows(shtname).Activate

Set cliente = Sheets("Dados").Range("C10")
Set CPE = Sheets("Dados").Range("C15")
Set localidade = Sheets("Dados").Range("C13")
Set table1 = Sheets("Cálculos").Range("B5:K17")

'word's bookmark

'cabeçalho
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("cliente4").Range.Text = cliente

'rodapé
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("num_proposta4").Range.Text = numproposta

 'corpo texto
 Set BMRange = WDDoc.Goto(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="cliente1")
 BMRange.Text = cliente

 Set BMRange = WDDoc.Goto(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Table")
 BMRange.Text = table1

'Guardar word na pasta das propostas
With wdApp.ActiveDocument
saveAsName = "C:\Users\PT13217294\test.docm"
ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=saveAsName
wdApp.Quit
End With

Set BMRange = Nothing
Set WDDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
```

What should i do to fix this?
Thanks in advance,

André

Comment: First of all, you should use `Option Explicit` for programming... Second, check variable names within your code- you have `table1` and then you are trying to put into bookmark `talbe` which is...nothing...

Comment: Oh, it was my mistake when i was copying the code to here. It has the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign `Excel Range Object` (which is `table1` in your code) to `Word Range.Text Properties`. In such situation we usually need to copy>>paste between two applications.

Therefore you need to do the following:

```
'....your code here
Set BMRange = WDDoc.Goto(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Table")
'new code for you
    table1.Copy
    BMRange.Paste
'rest of your code
'Guardar word na pasta das propostas
With wdApp.ActiveDocument
'...and so on
```

If it's required you need to experiment with table formation when pasting.
The above solution is tried and tested.

Comment: I change that code segment to what u suggest:
    -`Set BMRange = WDDoc.Goto(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Table")`
    `table1.Copy`
    `BMRange.Paste`


And i get a compile error: Method or data member not found.

Answer (score 0):

After you use Kaz's suggestion (`Option Explicit` prevents this sort of error), once you have copied the table, you can try something like this (untested):

```
Dim wdRange as Object
Set wdRng = WDDoc.Bookmarks("Table").Range
wdApp.Goto(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Table")
wdApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdTableOriginalFormatting '## Modify as needed
```

You may need to add some logic to delete existing table shapes, prior to pasting the new one in.

I think if you delete, then you *might* also need to do this (I have this in my example Excel-->Word macro, but it's been a while since I used it):

```
wdApp.Selection.Bookmarks.Add "Table", wdRng
```